# Python Program to convert complicated json into csv for a complete beginner

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I understand the very basics of programming in python and here is my problem. I have following json file from the developer API for League of Legends (a video game) (excerpt):

```
 "keys": {
          "35": "Shaco",
          "36": "DrMundo",
          "33": "Rammus",
          AND SO ON..
       },
       "data": {
           "Aatrox": {
               "tags": [
                   "Fighter",
                   "Tank"
               ],
                "stats": {
                    "attackrange": 150,
                    "mpperlevel": 45,
                    "mp": 105.6,
                    "attackdamage": 60.376,
                    AND SO ON...

             },
             AND SO ON.
```

My code:

```
#import dependencies
#to understand json
import json

#to write csv file
import csv

#to output json in a readable way in the command line
from pprint import pprint

#create the output file
outfile_path='output.csv'

#open up the file and tell the programm to write in it
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'w'))


#Create custom headers for the data
headers =['armor', 'armorperlevel', 'attackdamage','attackdamageperlevel','attackrange', 'attackspeedoffset', 'attackspeedperlevel', 'crit', 'critperlevel', 'hp', 'hpperlevel', 'hpregen', 'hpregenperlevel', 'movespeed', 'mp', 'mpperlevel', 'mpregen', 'mpregenperlevel', 'spellblock', 'spellblockperlevel']
writer.writerow(headers)

#open data file, in order to manipulate it
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

#print stats for the keys Aatrox
aatrox = data['data']['Aatrox']['stats']
pprint(aatrox)
```

What I have done so far:

- I was able to load the file in my program
- I created custom headers in a csv file
- I am able to print the data for a specific "keys" (ex: Aatrox)
- I can also print the "stats" of a specific "keys"

What I would like to do now:

- Create a line in a CSV-file for each "keys" with the "stats"-value separated by commas

I believe that I will be able to create a loop that goes through all the keys by myself. However I fail to find easy to understand information on how to write the dictionary to a CSV-file in my desired format.
Could anyone help me out with this. What I am most interested in understanding is:

- How do I write a dictionary-value to a string with a specific format?
- How can I tell python to put the dictionary-value under the correct
  header, which I have specified?

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of your desired output csv-file in order to make clear how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv

stats =  {
    "attackrange": 150,
    "mpperlevel": 45,
    "mp": 105.6,
    "attackdamage": 60.376,}

headers =['attackdamage','attackrange', 'mp', 'mpperlevel']

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        f, headers, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', )
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(stats)
```

produces `output.csv`:

```
attackdamage,attackrange,mp,mpperlevel
60.376,150,105.6,45
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as desired. For people having a similiar problem as I, I recommend to read the documentation of csv.DictWriter.